# Dom7 - getJson works but unable to transfer data

Tags: javascript, json, html-framework-7, dom7

I'm working on top of Urban Dictionary api example of Framework7.

This is the resulting JSON from the url (**edit** don't ask me why but it starts with an 'a'):

```
a{
  "bills": [
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name_id": "6",
      "category_id": 4,
      "isPaid": "Yes",
      "value": "190.00",
      "expiry": "2016-12-15 00:00:00",
      "created_at": "2017-01-04 15:44:00",
      "updated_at": "2017-01-04 15:44:00",
      "name": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Test1",
        "created_at": "2017-01-04 15:39:45",
        "updated_at": "2017-01-04 15:39:45"
      },
      "category": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "System",
        "created_at": "2017-01-04 15:37:43",
        "updated_at": "2017-01-04 15:37:43"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the piece of code on my-app.js:

```
function getrandom() {
  // Get JSON Data from UrbanDictionary API 
  $$.getJSON('http://[privateurl]', function (json) {

// Insert rendered template
    $$('#content-wrap').html(compiledTemplate(json));
  });
};
```

I try to get the results by doing: `console.log(getrandom());`

I get: `Undefined`

It doesn't load my list.

```
              {{#each list}}
              <li>
                <a href="{{bill_id}}" class="item-link item-content external" target="_blank">
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-title-row">
                      <div class="item-title">"{{bill_id}}"</div>
                      <div class="item-text">by {{value}}</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              {{/each}}
```

However, if I do this: `console.log($$.getJSON('http://hiddenapiurl'));`

I get results just fine.

**edit**: The actual urban dictionary api works normally. But mine doesn't for some reason.

**EDIT2**

Below is the whole code for my-app.js:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({});

var $$ = Dom7;

// Select Template
var template = $$('#random-template').html();

// Compile and render
var compiledTemplate = Template7.compile(template);

// Defined as function "getrandom"
function getrandom() {
  $$.getJSON('http://[privateurl]', function (json) {

    // Insert rendered template
    console.log(json);
    $$('#content-wrap').html(compiledTemplate(json));
  });
};


console.log($$.getJSON('http://[privateurl]'));

getrandom();

// Select Pull to refresh content
var ptrContent = $$('.pull-to-refresh-content');

// On refresh
ptrContent.on('refresh', function (e) {
  // Emulate 1s loading
  setTimeout(function () {

    // Execute getrandom to get new Definitions
    getrandom();

    myApp.pullToRefreshDone();
  }, 1000);
});


var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
  dynamicNavbar: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `getrandom()` function does not have a `return`, that's why `console.log(getrandom())` says `Undefined`!

Second, where did you select the template that you are compiling with `compiledTemplate`?

For example:

```
    var searchTemplate = $('#list-template').html();
    var compiledSearchTemplate = Template7.compile(searchTemplate);

    myApp.onPageInit('search', function (page) {
        // Just execute compiled search template with required content:
        var html = compiledSearchTemplate({/*...some data...*/});

        // Do something with html...
    });
```

Please double check the Framework7 example.

**EDIT 2:**

Why are you saying `each list` while your json array name is `bills`?
Try using `each bills` or `each this.bills`.

And the `a` that is bothering you because your json file has an `a` letter at the beginning of it!

[image]

Good luck man!

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I figured that out long ago. What intrigues me is that if I slap `console.log(json);` inside the function it just doesn't return anything when it runs. If I switch out the API to something else, it works fine. Another thing that is bothering me is that my json starts with the alphabet 'a' for some reason. I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Added the whole code as an edit to the main post, thanks.

Comment: Oh shit, you're right. However, it still doesn't work. I feel I'm close to it. For my backend I'm using laravel, and I have absolutely **no idea** why it's outputting that a. What I'm sure of is that it's not reading it as json, maybe because of that `a`, or maybe because of a header? More likely because of that `a`. Will keep trying, thanks.

Comment: If you'd like to share a live example of the exact situation, i'll be glad to help.